# Scala - functional methods - expected NotInferedA

Tags: scala

I have to Strings which represent two html site contents. I want to remove whitespaces and comments, compute Levenshtein distance between them and on that basis I want to decide wether they are similiar or not.
I created functions:

```
  val removeWhiteSpacesAndHtmlComments: String => String = _.replaceAll("\\s+","\\s").replaceAll("<!--.*?-->","")
  val prepareContents: (String,String) => (String,String) = (s1,s2) => (removeWhiteSpacesAndHtmlComments.apply(s1), removeWhiteSpacesAndHtmlComments(s2))
  val computeLevenshteinDistance:(String,String) => Int = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(_,_)
  val areContentsSimilarEnough: Int => Boolean = _ <= 50
```

I want to combine all those functions into a flow:

```
val isHtmlContentChanged: (String,String) => Boolean = prepareContents.tupled andThen computeLevenshteinDistance andThen areContentsSimilarEnough
```

Unfortunately over the `computeLevenshteinDistance` part I get exception:

```
Type mismatch, expected: (String,String) => NotInferedA, actual: (String,String)=>Int
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: I believe you just forgot the .tupled on computeLevenshteinDistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.tupled` to `computeLevenshteinDistance`.

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/WqCvFVi/1)